# message : "div is not defined"

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma função para esconder uma div e abrir os dados com um href. Ele funciona em outro form normalmente, mas não funciona neste form que preciso que funciona, ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> message : "div is not defined"

Segue a função:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Localiza o elemento
  var div = document.getElementById('minha_div');
  // Esconde a DIV
  div.style.display = 'none';
  // O link
  var clique = document.getElementById('clique');

  // Captura o evento de clique no link
  clique.onclick = function() {
    alert('clique');
    // Verifica se getComputedStyle é suportado
    if ('getComputedStyle' in window) {
      var display = window.getComputedStyle(div).display;
    } else {
      // Obtém a opção display para navegadores antigos
      var display = div.currentStyle.display;
    }

    // Verifica se display é none
    if (display == 'none') {
      // Muda para display block
      div.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      // Muda para display none
      div.style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Retorna falso para não atualizar a página
    return false;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<span class="fundo_clique">
    <a href="#" id="clique">Para configurar as mensagens, clique aqui!</a>
</span>
<br />
<%-- MODAL FINANCEIRO LANÇAMENTO DE CONTAS --%>
<span id="minha_div" style="border: none" runat="server">*conteúdo*</span>
```

Eu creio que os problemas estejam nas referências, pois em outro form que não precisa dessas referências funciona, e neste eu preciso destas:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile/pessoas_small_1366.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="javascript/pessoa.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
```

Mas de toda forma que eu mudo, acontece a mesma coisa.

O que pode ser?

Comment: problema parece ser que vc definiu a variável `div` no load da página quando é possível que ainda não exista a div. De qq modo usar variáveis globais dessa forma não é o recomendado. Tente mover o getelement para dentro da função ou crie uma função que retorna essa div e use-a

Comment: Esta sua função está declarada onde? O teu problema provavelmente é que estás a executar esta função antes da `minha_div` existir

Comment: @jean consegui resolver dessa forma, mudei e deu certo, obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro problema (não relacionado), tem dois jQuerys sem necessidade:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ou usa um ou usa outro

Segundo, o erro não parece ser no código acima descrito, pois mesmo que o elemento não exista na página o erro que ocorria seria algo como:

> Cannot read property 'style' of null

**Já o erro**

> is not defined

Ocorre quando não existe a variável no escopo de uma função, então provavelmente você tem alguma outra variável `div` em **outro script**, ou seja `$.ready` e `window.onload` não tem haver com a solução, o problema **É O ESCOPO** de acesso da variável.

Comment: Não entendo porque do DOWNVOTE, eu expliquei a diferença entre ambas mensagens de erro, é óbvio que o erro não tem haver como ser resolvido, pois o problema esta em outro lugar, o que fiz foi responder dentro do possivel, explicar que é o ESCOPO de acesso, ou seja a variavel foi criada em um escopo e o AP esta tentando acessar em outro.

Comment: cara desculpa ia votar , e acabei dando donwvote, sua resposta foi muito boa, acabei de editar

Comment: @MarceloBatista pode deixar assim, pode ser também o que o PauloHDSouza disse. Só queria saber se eu tinha confundido algo. Obrigado de qualquer forma pelo retorno ;)

Comment: nao cara erro foi meu, li a sua resposta adequeda por sinal e acabei errando, mais vale como aprendizado, atentar-se ao votar

Comment: Haha que hilário, eu ia responder exatamente a mesma coisa tendo em vista o escopo do `var` não fazer parte do escopo da função do clique, tinha certeza disso, mas aí eu vi que a variável foi acessada e fiquei bem confuso, no fim das contas não tive a certeza e só comentei algo na pergunta. Mas eu não imaginei que outra variável `div` poderia estar sendo acessada ao invés da desejada. Fica como aprendizado para quando eu duvidar de mim mesmo me certificar que não há nenhuma chance de algo externo estar atrapalhando :P

Answer (score 1):

Simples, você esta com a div **RUNAT=SERVER** , logo o ID irá alterar por que essa div roda server side, tente pegar pela classe

```
 <span class="minha_div" id="minha_div" style="border: none" runat="server">*conteúdo*</span>
```

E no seu .js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var minhaDiv = $('.minha_div'); 
});
```

Comment: acho que você matou a charada, ma não precisa fazer a seleção por uma classe, basta mudar o selector para considerar o sufixo do  atributo,  $("[id*='minha_div']")

Comment: Pode ser também.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que está incluindo o Jquery tente isso:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var div = $('#minha_div');
  div.css( "display", "none" );
  resto do seu código....   
});
```

Remova o seu **onload** e tente **$(document).ready**

A diferença é que a div só sera escondida quando o DOM estiver sido todo lido. Então é chamado essa função por callback que esconde o seu elemento. O callback ira evitar que a função execute antes do html ser todo carregado no navegador uma vez que o javascript é um linguagem assincrona.

***O que são Fluxos assíncronos?***

Mesmo que projetado para ter um único fluxo de execução, algumas tarefas do seu programa JavaScript poderão ser executadas sem interferir em nada o fluxo principal de execução de código. Essas tarefas são conhecidas como fluxos assíncronos. Você pode disparar uma série dessas tarefas sem precisar esperar que cada uma se complete para prosseguir. Nos computadores atuais, que possuem mais de um núcleo de processamento, algumas tarefas do escopo do seu programa poderão inclusive ser executadas no mesmo instante do seu código.

Answer (score 0):

Se você usa várias bibliotecas (jQuery, Bootstrap entre outras relacionadas), teria mais sentido você usar o próprio jQuery para simplesmente mostrar e esconder a `div`, reduzindo drasticamente o código, e não sendo preciso, inclusive, fazer verificação de compatibilidade com `if ('getComputedStyle' in window)`.

Além do que, com o código abaixo sugerido, nenhum erro será retornado em relação à `div` (pelo menos no exemplo dado na pergunta), sendo que as funções e variáveis dentro de `$(window).on('load', function(){` só serão invocadas após o carregamento da página.

Veja que com apenas **9 linhas** com jQuery, dá pra fazer a mesma coisa que você quer fazer com mais de **20 linhas** de código em JavaScript:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
   var div = $('#minha_div'); // Localiza o elemento
   div.hide(); // Esconde a DIV
   $('#clique').click(function(e){ // Captura o evento de clique no link
      alert('clique');
      div.is(':visible') ? div.hide() : div.show(); // pega o estado da div e mostra/esconde
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
   var div = $('#minha_div'); // Localiza o elemento
   div.hide(); // Esconde a DIV
   $('#clique').click(function(e){ // Captura o evento de clique no link
      alert('clique');
      div.is(':visible') ? div.hide() : div.show(); // pega o estado da div e mostra/esconde
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="fundo_clique">
   <a href="#" id="clique">Para configurar as mensagens, clique aqui!</a>
</span>
<br />
<span id="minha_div" style="border: none" runat="server">*conteúdo*</span>
```